# How to get all radio button group selections from a form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, radio-button, form-submit

I have a form with many groups of radio buttons which are dynamically generated from a database of questions. They look like this:

```
<input name="group{{../questionNumber}}" type="radio" id="q{{../questionNumber}}_{{answerLetter}}" value="{{answerLetter}}" />
```

where `((questionNumber}}` is just an integer (they go in order from 1) and `{{answerLetter}}` will be a letter starting from `A` again for each new question, meaning that question 1, answer 2 will have `name="group1"` and `id=q1_B`.

When the user submits the form I would like to get all their answers, but so far I only know how to get an answer by explicitly typing out the `name` properties value:

```
Template.Test.events({
  "submit #Test": function (event, template) {

    // var element = template.find('input:radio[name=group1]:checked');
    // alert($(element).val());

    alert(event.target.group1.value)

    return false;
  }
});
```

`#Test` is the `form` `id`.

How could I dynamically get all the `value` values into an array? Also can I get the number of radiobutton groups easily inside the above function or is it easier to query that from my database?

Comment: As clippy would say, "It looks like you are building a survey system..."

Comment: No, it's a multiple choice test. But functionally the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all checked radios whos name starts with "group" this way:

```
var groups = {};
$('#Test').find('input[name^="group"]:checked').each(function(){
    var this_name = $(this).attr('name');
    var this_value = $(this).val();
    groups[this_name] = this_value;
});
```

Now the found radios are they keys of the object `groups` so you can count them like so:

```
var count = 0;
for (var k in groups) 
    if (groups.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
        ++count;
```

The radio values are the values of the keys in that object.